# ionic same codebase for ipad and iphone

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a fully fledged app built with ionic and angularjs which is running fine on ipad and android.Now we have decided to release it for iphone and android phones with some design changes.Is there any way to do so with the same codebase as the functionality remains same and only the html changes.I read the documentation for ionic platform but it seems it is only for differentiating android and ios platform.Any help is appreciated,thanks

Comment: If the functionality is same, then you can just make your design changes and you are ready to go.

Comment: but that design changes will distort the design on the ipad and android tablets

Comment: You will have to use media queries to make the effect applicable only on small devices.

Comment: I don't want to use media queries,Is there any other way it can be done

Comment: Any reason for not using media queries?
As an alternative, you can create a separate project for iphones and android devices with same codebase but with all your design changes.

Comment: The reason for not using media query would be because there are minor changes like instead of having one big section on ipad we have two switchable tabs(section) on mobile devices.I suppose then we are only left with two different projects with the same codebase.My concern is what would happen if we upload it to app store or play store,will we say this is for tablets and this is for mobile devices?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a separate project for iphones and android devices with same codebase but with all your design changes.

And Yes, you can specify in the App Store. you will have two urls now, One for ipad apps and one for iphones.